How to add lifecycle hooks to users_permissions collection
I have created a profiles collection, including my custom fields for users which has a 1-to-1 relation with the default Strapi (V4) users_permissions_users collection.
To do so, I'm trying to add a lifecycle hook to the existing users_permissions_users model.
I've added the file in src/extensions/users-permissions/content-types/user/lifecycles.js, and the content looks like
export default {
   async afterCreate(event) {
      // My custom logic here
   }
}

but this function is never called. It seems like Strapi never subscribes to this lifecycle hook.
Is it the name of the file that's wrong or should I register it somewhere else as do the plugins?

You may refer to this thread: https://forum.strapi.io/t/strapi-create-new-user-users-permissions-plugin-lifecycles/13386/2
